# Sortable no funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

he estado buscando la solucion para estre problema pero no encuentro forma.
Tengo una funcion que crea un ul (sortable) dentro de un div y una ya creada en el html, la cuestion es que cuando esa funcion crea el ul, no lo crea con las propiedades de un sortable.
Para asignar esas propiedades cree la funcion **AsignarPropiedad**, pero esta no afecta al momento de crear el **div2** con el ul

```
<html>
<div id="div1">
   <ul class="connectedSortable sortable">
      <li>Uno</li>
      <li>Dos</li>
      <li>Tres</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
</html>

<script>
function AsignarPropiedad()
{
   $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
   }).disableSelection();
}
AsignarPropiedad();    
$('#div2').append('<ul class="connectedSortable sortable"><li>Numeros</li></ul>')
</script>
```

Lo que quiero es que tanto como el primer sortable del div1 y del div2 funcionen entre si y se pueda arrastrar los li

Comment: Primero llamas a asignarPropiedad (cuando no existe el ul de div2) y luego creas el div2. Creo que sí cambias el orden de esas llamadas y pones a lo último el AsignarPropiedad te añadirá las propiedades. Pero como eso se aplica a todos los sortables, se aplicará dos veces en el div1

Comment: @Jakala Si era eso, pensaba que se colocaba las propiedades automaticamente, igual como los estilos, gracias